# Implementing spinlocks to synchronize OpenMP threads using compiler intrinsics

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, intrinsics

Please take a look at the following code snippet using OpenMP for parallelization:

```
char lock = 0;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&lock, 0, 1));
    printf("Thread: %d is working!\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    sleep(1);
    printf("Thread: %d unlocks lock!\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    lock = 0;
}
```

Is it possible, that threads simultaneously lock the lock, even though the locking is atomic with __sync_bool_compare_and_swap?
For example, not all threads having a consistent view of the memory?

Comment: While `__sync_*()` is a full barrier, `lock = 0;` is not.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? OpenMP is exactly made to provide proper abstractions, e.g. `#pragma omp crtical` in your case. From the [description of `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html), I would strongly assume that memory barriers are used to enforce a consistent view of memory. But as noticed by EOF, the `lock = 0;` can be a problem due to reordering.

Comment: While I completely agree with you, I am currently working with code I have not written and in this code, synchronization is reinforced the way I presented it in the code. And Intel Inspector detects race conditions, which should not be possible if the synchronization is working as I expect it to do.

Comment: Is it conceivable that the Intel Inspector produces false positives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** you insist on not doing this the OpenMP way:

You definitely need a compiler barrier to prevent `lock=0` from being [reordered at compile time](http://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/).

If you're only targeting x86, just a compiler barrier is fine;  Otherwise use a [C11 `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) before `lock=0`, which is just a compiler barrier on x86 but will emit the necessary instructions on weakly ordered architectures.

Or make `lock` an atomic type, and use a C11 stdatomic release-store to set it to 0.

---

Spinning on a `lock cmpxchg` to take the lock is pretty inefficient.  You should spin on a load until the lock is available, then try to take it.  e.g. you should write something that will compile to code [like this minimal but real asm spinlock implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241553/locks-around-memory-manipulation-via-inline-assembly/37246263#37246263)

e.g. use a C11 atomic load with `memory_order_acquire`.  Then use a normal `xchg`, not a `cmpxchg`, and check if you got the lock or if another thread took it before you did.