# Any disadvantages for std::atomic_flag not providing load or store operations? (Spin-lock example)

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

Comparing a [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) to an `std::atomic_bool` (aka [`std::atomic<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)), it seems to me that a `std::atomic_flag` just has a simpler interface. It provides only testing+setting and clearing the flag while an `std::atomic_bool` also provides overloads to several operators.

One question of mine is about terminology: What is meant by "load or store operations"? Does it mean that it is not possible to arbitrarily read and modify a `std::atomic_flag`'s value?

Furthermore, I am wondering, could a `std::atomic_bool` be faster when being used for a spin-lock? It seems to me that an `std::atomic_flag` always must read AND write during a spin-lock:

```
while (my_atomic_flag.test_and_set()); // spin-lock
```

while an `std::atomic_bool` would only have to perform a read operation (assuming that the atomic bool is implemented lock-free):

```
while (my_atomic_bool); // spin-lock
```

Is an `std::atomic_flag` strictly more efficient than an `std::atomic_bool` or could it also be the other way round? What should be used for a spin-lock?

Comment: `while (my_atomic_bool);` doesn't implement spin lock, `while (my_atomic_flag.test_and_set());` does.

Comment: Ah, you are right... what I've posted is not actually a spin-lock but rather a spin-wait (because I was using that in the project I'm currently on). One thread has to wait until the other thread is done with something. So, I guess, it's more a semaphore-kind-of-use-case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is meant by "load or store operations"? Does it mean that it is not possible to arbitrarily read and modify a std::atomic_flag's value?

The normal store/load operations are not supported on a `std::atomic_flag`.
It is a modify-only type; ie. you cannot read-access a `std::atomic_flag` object without performing a modifying operation.
In general, `std::atomic_flag` is meant as a building block for other operations. It's interface is deliberately simple; it is the only atomic type that has guaranteed atomic lock-free operations.
The operations it supports are:

```
std::atomic_flag::clear()
std::atomic_flag::test_and_set()
```

With that, you can easily build your own spinlock (although generally not recommended):

```
class my_spinlock {
    std::atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
public:

    void lock()
    {
        while(flag.test_and_set());
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        flag.clear();
    }
};
```

> Furthermore, I am wondering, could a std::atomic_bool be faster when being used for a spin-lock? It seems to me that an std::atomic_flag always must read AND write during a spin-lock

Well, the thing is, a spinlock *always* has to modify its state when acquiring the lock. You simply cannot take a lock without telling others.
The implementation for `lock()` based on a `std::atomic<bool>` looks very similar:

```
while (flag.exchange(true));
```

Whether a spinlock based on `std::atomic_flag` is faster ?
On my platform, the compiler emits the same assembly for both types so I would be very surprised.

Comment: Well, you can implement spin-lock with double checked locking which will do only load operations most of the time instead of RMW which is the only option for `std::atomic_flag`. Will it yield much difference? I doubt it, but still.

Comment: @ixSci: My understanding is that you normally want to spin read-only until you see the lock available, then try to take it.  Then the cache line can be in "shared" state in all the waiting threads, instead of having them all flood the bus with invalidate requests to take exclusive ownership of it and bounce it around.  The problem with the last part of this answer is spinning on `atomic<bool>::exchange` is not a good implementation, but you can't write anything better with `atomic_flag`.  See [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246263)

Comment: Of course, you need platform-specific stuff to make an actually *good* spinlock.  e.g. x86's `pause` / `_mm_pause()` instruction, and fallback to OS-assisted sleep/wake.  But I *think* in general a hand-rolled spinlock using `atomic<bool>` (if `is_always_lock_free`) would be slightly less bad than one using `atomic_flag`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, that's pretty much what I meant. I'm just not sure that one or another implementation would be best in all cases. For example, you will lose less races with `exchange` but will hit cache harder. So everything depends on the task, I believe. Anyway if the OP has such questions I would not write custom spinlocks if I were him.

Comment: @ixSci: Hmm, with SMT (e.g. Hyperthreading), spinning on `xchg` would block the logical core more of the time, allowing non-waiting threads to run more instructions.  It might also save power overall vs. spinning read-only, if we don't have the `pause` instruction available in fully portable code.  So yeah, it's less clear than I was thinking that `.exchange()` is worse for a fully generic implementation.  I wouldn't encourage *anyone* to write custom spinlocks using *generic* portable C++; real ones are carefully tuned with exponential backoff and stuff like `pause`.

Comment: @ixSci: "losing less races" is just because it spins slower.  After an unlock, yeah multiple threads will get the cache line in Shared state, and then race with each other to get it in Modified state for the actual `exchange`.  Exactly one thread will win, while some others did see it unlocked but lost that race.  But I don't see how that's relevant because they don't slow down the thread that did win.  Its `.exchange()` completes first, that's *why* it won.