# Understanding of C++'s std::atomic<T> and compare-and-swap

Tags: c++, atomic, compare-and-swap

My understanding is that compare-and-swap is something supported by hardware, e.g., CMPXCHG in x86 architecture. I have the following two confusions:

- Is it that C++'s atomic does not "implement" atomicity itself, but rather it leverages the atomic functions of CPUs?
- But what if an architecture does not have compare-and-swap functions? If a compiler on that platform wants to be C++ standard-compliant, it has to find some other (probably much more computationally expensive) ways to implement `std::atomic` without using compare-and-swap approach?

Comment: compare-and-swap can be implemented on top of LL/SC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional, along with other atomic RMW operations on a single object.  LL/SC is why `compare_exchange_weak` exists.

Answer (score 2):

Specializations of `std::atomic` are not generally required to be lock-free.

On a platform that doesn't support the required operations for a type `X` atomically, the C++ implementation can still implement `std::atomic<X>` with the help of a mutex. That way you can simply do the comparison and swap operations in multiple instructions which do not need to make any atomicity/ordering guarantees while holding a lock on the mutex.

To test whether a specialization of `std::atomic` is lock-free, use [`std::atomic<X>::is_always_lock_free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_always_lock_free) or the weaker form [`std::atomic<X>::is_lock_free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free).

The only type that is required to provide lock-free atomic operations on a conforming C++ implementation is [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) which has only two states and provides fewer operations than `std::atomic` and can be fully implemented by an atomic exchange of a byte, which the platform needs to provide for (plus a pure load in C++20 and later).

A `std::atomic_flag` is sufficient to implement locking, so that it is sufficient to implement all `std::atomic` specializations, but not lock-free.

The above requirements can be satisfied with the help of the OS scheduler by always having only one C++ thread run at the same time, effectively using only a single physical thread. But for actual concurrent multi-threading the hardware needs to provide the above-mentioned mechanisms. Depending on what atomic operations the CPU/instruction set supports on which size of operands, the `std::atomic` specializations will be implemented as lock-free using these operations, or instead using a locking mechanism.

Comment: do you mean that `std::atomic` or `mutex`, hardware support is almost always needed to have multi-thread synchronization? If hardware support does not exist, language itself is almost impossible to achieve multh-thread synchronization?

Comment: Worth pointing out that the only operations supported on `std::atomic_flag` are ones that can be done with an atomic exchange of a byte or word.  (C++20 adds a pure load function.)  I think I've read that some actual old hardware had swap as the only atomic RMW.  This is insufficient to implement lock-free `.fetch_add()` or CAS, but can implement locks.  (@D.J.Elkind)

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: On a uniprocessor system, the OS could provide the required atomicity by asking it not to context-switch to another thread (of this process or at all) until after you're done.  Or by having atomic ops as system calls, and perhaps the OS implements them by disabling interrupts.  (With only one CPU, the only way for other threads to run is if this thread is if this core switches to another thread between instructions of a multi-step thing.  Unlike with multi-core systems where another thread can be running simultaneously.)

Comment: @user17732522 for simplicity, let's just say on x86: do `std::atomic` and `std::mutex` rely on two different synchronization mechanisms? `std::atomic` is generally considered faster because the synchronization mechanism is used is faster (than the sync mechanism used by `std::mutex`)?

Comment: @PeterCordes if I get you correctly, you mean that if my computer has one CPU (and one thread) only, then it is possible to achieve multi-thread synchronization withOUT hardware support (as all "threads" are logical ones). but if we have a multi-core CPU, it is very unlikely (if not completely impossible) to implement  multi-thread synchronization without hardware support. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind That depends on which `std::atomic` specialization you are looking at. For those where it is possible, the compiler will just use x86 instructions to provide lock-free atomic operations. Otherwise it will be implemented as if with a `std::mutex`. How `std::mutex` is implemented may vary depending on the OS.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: I'm talking about a machine with one hardware execution context, e.g. a single-core CPU without hyperthreading / SMT or anything similar.  But such a machine can still run multiple software threads, just like we did in real life on such machines, like typical desktop/laptop systems before Intel Core Duo and AMD Phenom.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: *Let's just say on x86: do std::atomic and std::mutex rely on two different synchronization mechanisms* - No, they use the same underlying hardware support for atomic RMWs.  In theory you can implement mutual exclusion without atomic RMWs, just sequentially consistent loads/stores, but that would be slower on machines that can efficiently do atomic RMWs.  e.g. [Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246263)  (`xchg  al, [rdi]` is `std::atomic<uint8_t>.exchange()`, `mov byte [rdi], 0` is `.store(0, release)`.  And see the links there).

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: A few years ago, before Intel disabled it in microcode, some systems used to use HLE (Hardware Lock Elision) as an optional speedup for mutexes on CPUs that supported Intel's TSX transactional memory.  But it was guaranteed by the ISA to work as-if the lock's counter had actually been decremented and incremented.

Comment: @PeterCordes I saw the writeup on HLE a while back. It seemed pretty cool. What happened and why? Spectre et. al.? Is the RTM variant of TSX still being pursued?

Comment: @PeterCordes *No, they use the same underlying hardware support for atomic RMWs*--if so, why is `std::atomic` usually considered faster than `std::mutex`?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Sometimes `atomic` gets over-hyped; it can be slower if you need multiple operations in a group, when taking a lock would mean just one atomic RMW and multiple cheaper normal ops.  And on contention, if you just spin-retry with std::atomic instead of using `.wait` and `.notify`, you can waste a bunch of CPU time that could have been making throughput progress on other threads.  But, if you implement an algorithm that's actually lock-free using std::atomic, spin-retry does more often make sense.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind:  If you need an atomic counter, using one atomic RMW to just do that is cheaper than using an atomic RMW do take a lock, then a plain increment, then a store to unlock the mutex.  (Or worse, another atomic RMW, depending on the mutex implementation, especially if it has to detect the presence of other threads that have put themselves to sleep waiting for the mutex so can send a notify.  But doesn't want to unconditionally call `futex` even if there are no waiters, since system-calls are slow.)

Comment: @D.J.Elkind: Even better, `std::atomic` allows multiple readers in parallel to be truly read-only, no contention with any other threads, the cache line can be hot in MESI Shared state in multiple cores at once.  Pure loads are where `std::atomic` really shines, even more than in atomic RMWs.  (And pure stores are good, too.)  With any kind of mutex, even a readers/writers lock, a thread still has to do an atomic RMW on the mutex to increment the readers count, which is garbage compared to just reading a single `atomic<int64_t>`.

Comment: @CraigEstey: The most recent round of disabling TSX stuff in microcode was due to microarchitectural-data-sampling (MDS) type vulns, including TAA, not Spectre. (https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html)  I don't precisely know why HLE is permanently gone, but yes apparently RTM can still be enabled by the OS if it chooses.  [Has Hardware Lock Elision gone forever due to Spectre Mitigation?](//stackoverflow.com/q/61310108) / https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c2955f270a84762343000f103e0640d29c7a96f3